# In R, How to let update() find a variable created inside the function calling update()?

Tags: r

I want to call `update()` to re-fit a model inside a function. I want to keep the variable to be added inside the function. However, `update()` usually works by evaluating the `call` in the environment returned by `parent.frame()`. How can I insert the local variable in the search such that `update` can find it?

This works if done in the console:

```
set.seed(8700)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
z_global <- rnorm(10)
lm_out <- lm(y ~ x)
update(lm_out, . ~ . + z_global)
```

The output is:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z_global)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x     z_global  
    0.08648      0.49040      0.18212
```

However, this is what I want to do:

```
set.seed(8700)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
lm_out <- lm(y ~ x)
tmpfct <- function(fit) {
    z_local <- rnorm(10)
    update(fit, . ~ . + z_local)
  }
tmpfct(lm_out)
```

It does not work:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'z_local' not found
```

I guess it is because `update()` evaluates the call of `fit` in `parent.frame()`, which is the calling environment of `tmpfct(lm_out)`, that is, the global environment. `z_local` is not defined there.

I tried to insert an environment in the function, hoping that the `parent.frame()` in `update()` will be the execution environment of this function. However, this also does not work:

```
set.seed(8700)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
lm_out <- lm(y ~ x)
tmpfct <- function(fit) {
    z_local <- rnorm(10)
    tmp_env <- new.env(environment())
    eval(update(fit, . ~ . + z_local), envir = tmp_env)
  }
tmpfct(lm_out)
```

The error message is the same:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'z_local' not found
```

How should I modify the code such that when evaluating the call, `update()` can find `z_local` created inside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: OP's request:**

Without using `z_local` as second argument:

```
set.seed(8700)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
lm_out <- lm(y ~ x)
tmpfct <- function(fit) {
    update(fit, . ~ . + rnorm(10))
}
tmpfct(lm_out)
```

**First answer:**
You miss the second argument `z_local`:

```
set.seed(8700)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
lm_out <- lm(y ~ x)
tmpfct <- function(fit, z_local) {
    z_local <- rnorm(10)
    update(fit, . ~ . + z_local)
}
tmpfct(lm_out)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z_local)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x      z_local  
    0.08648      0.49040      0.18212
```

Comment: Thanks, TarJae. It works

Can I do this without exposing z_local as an argument? z_local is not supposed to be used by users of the function. In some of my scenarios that update other models, z_local can be a function. Users should not and do not need to know of the existence of z_local. I can add this argument and tell the users to ignore it. It would be better to do this without this argument.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer did solve the problem in my example. It's my fault. I should have used an example more specific to my intended question. `z_local` needs to be something dynamically determined inside the function when it is called. That's why the line `z_local <- rnorm(10)`. Therefore, it needs to be passed as a symbol when calling `update`. Replacing it by its content works in that example but does not work if it needs to be passed as a symbol for which `update` needs to find in the environments.