# Pass a function to `update` defined inside the function calling `update`

Tags: r

I want to call `update` inside a function. However, the argument to be passed (a) must a symbol referring to a function, and (b) this function is created dynamically inside the function based on other arguments.

If something similar is done but in the global environment, the following code works:

```r
set.seed(8700)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
fctgen <- function(FUN, n) {
    function() do.call(FUN, list(n = n))
  }
z_global <- fctgen(rnorm, 10)
lm_out <- lm(y ~ x)
update(lm_out, . ~ . + z_global())

#Output
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x + z_global(10))
#
#Coefficients:
# (Intercept)             x  z_global(10)  
#     0.08648       0.49040       0.18212
```

The following version does not work because `z_local` is not in the environment in which `update` evaluates the updated call.

```r
set.seed(8700)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
lm_out <- lm(y ~ x)
fctgen <- function(FUN, n) {
    function() do.call(FUN, list(n = n))
  }
tmpfct1 <- function(fit, FUN) {
    z_local <- fctgen(FUN = FUN, n = nrow(model.frame(lm_out)))
    update(fit, . ~ . + z_local())
  }
tmpfct1(lm_out, rnorm)
# Error in z_local() : could not find function "z_local"
```

How can I let `update` find `z_local`? For some reasons, `z_local` must be passed as a symbol to `update`, and its definition will be generated dynamically inside the function. Therefore, I would like to see how this problem can be solved by somehow calling `update` (e.g., by `eval` with an alternative environment?) and let `update` find `z_local` itself when evaluating a call. The actual function I will pass to `update` is much more complicated than the one in the example, and so embedding its content directly in the argument to `update` is not an option.

(Note: This is similar to another question I asked : [In R, How to let update() find a variable created inside the function calling update()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789112/in-r-how-to-let-update-find-a-variable-created-inside-the-function-calling-up), and that example can indeed be solved. However, I have a different scenario that may need other solutions. Therefore, I create this question.)